# CSS display types: Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, css-float

I am trying to make a tab-based layout, I have it working if it is in a vertical orientation, but I would like to make them horizontal. When a tab is clicked, I would like to make a `div` expand then the tab is, I am having trouble with this. I also added an `X` for exiting. This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FFjSk/16/).

```
<div id="header">
<div id="music"><a href="#">Music</a></div>             
<div id="about"><a href="#">About</a></div>
<div id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
</div>

<div id="musicinfo">
<p>Music info div</p>
<p id='close'>x</p>
</div>

$("#music").click(function() {
$("#musicinfo").show();
$('#close').click(function() {
$("#musicinfo").hide();

});


});
```

I did not add jquery on my fiddle so that was not the reason it was not working. So i will change my question because i think this post will still help people. Any better ideas on how to do what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're using jQuery functions, but had not added jQuery to the fiddle. I've done that for you. Check your fiddle now.

Comment: Wait... What? Can you reword that for me?

Comment: lol thanks sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a simpler solution which doesn't use jQuery? I really don't understand why everyone wants to use it, even if it's not necessary... (I assume your question is how to make tab's content appear when you click its name)

http://jsfiddle.net/EPDqR/

```
<div id="header">
<div id="music" onclick="getElementById('musicinfo').style.display='block';"><a href="#">Music</a></div>             
<div id="about"><a href="#">About</a></div>
<div id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
</div>

<div id="musicinfo">
<p>Music info div</p>
<p id='close' onclick="getElementById('musicinfo').style.display='none';">x</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point i will try it your way. I am trying to learn jquery so i guess i try to always use it.

Comment: Not using jQuery is fine. But why do you wanna suggest age old practice of handling events. It should always be avoided. and a better way is to bind the events using javascript instead of handling them inline

Answer (score 1):

You have to import jQuery into fiddle

```
$("something")... // this is jQuery object
```

Now it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/FFjSk/23/